# Javascript inside php not working

Tags: php, html

I have a script inside php that will change the display of a `div` when a checkbox is checked, the checkbox location is different from the place where the script is located.

the snippets of the code is shown below

```
        if($_POST['test'] == 1)
        {
            echo "<script> document.getElementById('seoTerm').style.display='block';</script>";}
```

I placed the above code in the `head` of the current page. When the `$_POST['test']` is `1`, the display of the `div` with id `seoTerm` is still *none*, instead of *block*.

What's the problem here ?

Comment: you need to execute it on a event. because the dom may not be ready when your script is triggering now

Comment: try <script> instead of <script?>

Comment: What's the resulting HTML + JS?

Comment: @DevZer0 how to execute on an event ?

Comment: Is `div` with the id `seoTerm` located before or after the script tag?

Comment: Then see the answer of _Johan Bouveng_.  At the time the script is executed the element does not exist in the DOM, and could not be found.

Comment: @user2106416 check the answer of Johan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might fire to early in order to manipulate the DOM.

Try:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('seoTerm').style.display='block';
};
</script>
```

Comment: @user2106416 or you could also just move your `script` tag at a place behind the element with the id `seoTerm` it depends on what you want to achieve. The `onload` will be triggered when everything is loaded. If you move the `script` just behind it the element it will show immediately.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in the `script` tag

change to `<script>` and not `<script?>`

Comment: Make sure you have an element with id seoTerm

Comment: echo "<script>alert('Testing')</script>";
Try this just for testing.

Comment: Is javascript enabled in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
echo "<script>document.getElementById('seoTerm').style.display='block';</script>";
```

instead of

```
echo "<script?> document.getElementById('seoTerm').style.display='block';</script>";
```

Comment: refresh the page, i have edited, not suppose to have '?' , type when copying the code over

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions you need either use document.ready event or you can echo this code after the element is displayed.

If you do it before the element may not exsits when JavaScript tries to bind an event to it.

```
echo "<script>window.onload = function(){ document.getElementById('seoTerm').style.display='block'};</script>"
```